# How can I summarize this array by dates

Tags: javascript

How can I summarize this array by dates ?

```
[
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-11", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 10, b: 10, c: 0, d: 0 }
];
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Summarize? what you do mean by that. Explain what output do you expect.

Comment: I receive this answer: https://jsonfake.herokuapp.com/mongo, and I want to build an object, similar to this: data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ]
To use Morris JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something like this, then here is the answer.

```
var array = [
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-11", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 10, b: 10, c: 0, d: 0 }
];

function summarize(){
 let summarize = {};
 array.map(ele => {
    const {a, b, c, d, y} = ele;
    if(summarize[y]){
    summarize[y] = {a: summarize[y].a + a, b: summarize[y].b + b, c: summarize[y].c + c, d: summarize[y].d + d};
  }else{
    summarize[y] = {a,b,c,d};
  }
 });

 const keys = Object.keys(summarize);
 const newArray = [];
 keys.map(ele => {
    const {a,b,c,d} = summarize[ele];
    newArray.push({y: ele, a,b,c,d });
 });

 return newArray;
}

console.log(summarize());
```

This will give you out put as O/P

```
[
   {"y":"2019-01-10","a":35,"b":50,"c":10,"d":0},
   {"y":"2019-01-11","a":25,"b":40,"c":10,"d":0}
]
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I need, excellent response. I'm new to this thanks for the support

Comment: you are welcome, just ensure you elaborate your question as much as possible. Community is always here to help each other :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Array` `reduce`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const myArray = [ {y: "2019-01-10", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0}, {y: "2019-01-11", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0}, {y: "2019-01-10", a: 10, b: 10, c: 0, d: 0}];
const summaryObj = myArray.reduce((acc, item = {}) => {
  // You can do something like this:
  const date = item.y;// Just clarifying that "y" is a date for your purposes here.
  const existingDateObj = acc[date] || {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0};// Make sure a, b, c and d start out as numbers or your addition (undefined + 1) will result in `NaN`.

  // You could/should do this in an immutable way, but that's a topic for another answer ;)
  acc[date] = {
    // Add the values from each item to the current, accumulated (summarized) values for the same date as `item.y`.
    a: existingDateObj.a + item.a,
    b: existingDateObj.b + item.b,
    c: existingDateObj.c + item.c,
    d: existingDateObj.d + item.d
  };

  return acc;
}, {});// The empty object {} is the initial accumulator. (The blank/empty/base version of the thing you ultimately intend to return.)
```

At that point, `summaryObj` will look like this:

```
{
  "2019-01-10": {
    "a": 35,
    "b": 50,
    "c": 10,
    "d": 0
  },
  "2019-01-11": {
    "a": 25,
    "b": 40,
    "c": 10,
    "d": 0
  }
}
```

If you want an array back, you can iterate the keys:

```js
const myNewArray = Object
  .keys(summaryObj)
  .map(y => ({y, ...summaryObj[y]}));// Using object rest spread (...) for simplicity, it's the same as applying a, b, c and d (all the properties) for the current y value of summaryObj.
```

Then you would have this for `myNewArray`:

```
[
  {
    "y": "2019-01-10",
    "a": 35,
    "b": 50,
    "c": 10,
    "d": 0
  },
  {
    "y": "2019-01-11",
    "a": 25,
    "b": 40,
    "c": 10,
    "d": 0
  }
]
```

There are multiple ways to achieve this sort of task but this should give you some solid footing from which to base a solution.

> **NOTE:** Some of the syntax here is ES6+ and may or may not be available depending on the JavaScript environment where you are running your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you means to extract `y` (Date String) from this array then do [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-11", a: 25, b: 40, c: 10, d: 0 },
  { y: "2019-01-10", a: 10, b: 10, c: 0, d: 0 }
];

var Dates = data.map(x => x.y);
console.log(Dates)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I want is to add a, b, c, d according to the repeated dates

Comment: For example? Show us some output. it already has a,b,c,d ? then why add?